# implement onCreate() in native layer via JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I want to use reflection calls to invoke the `onCreate()` method via `JNI`, maybe like this:

```
 static {
     System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
 }

public native void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

now I've implement the part of its native cpp code, like this:

```
    Java_com_hack_nativeoc_MainActivity_onCreate(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject bundle)  
    {   
        jclass thisClass = (*env).GetObjectClass(thiz);
        jclass thisClassGlobal = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(thisClass));
        static jobject thizglobal = (*env).NewGlobalRef(thiz);
        jclass superClass=(*env).GetSuperclass(thisClass);
        jclass superClassGlobal = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(superClass));

        jmethodID superOnCreate = (*env).GetMethodID(superClassGlobal, "onCreate", "(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V");
       (*env).CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(thizglobal,superClassGlobal,superOnCreate,bundle);

        jclass rclass = env->FindClass("com/nisl/hack/nativeoc/R$layout");
        jclass globalClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(rclass));

        jfieldID activityID = env->GetFieldID(globalClass,"activity_main","I");
        jint activityMain = env->GetIntField(globalClass,activityID);



        jmethodID setContentView = (*env).GetMethodID(thisClassGlobal,"setContentView","(Landroid/view/View;)V");
        (*env).CallVoidMethod(thizglobal,setContentView,activityMain);}
```

but when I implement the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, it shows this error:

```
E/art: JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale weak global reference 0x7f04001b (should be 0x10001b)
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted weak global reference 0x7f04001b
```

how to solve this error? 
Here is the small part of detailed error message:

```
12-05 11:14:53.346 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc E/art: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale weak global reference 0x7f09001b (index 16390 in a table of size 361)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted weak global reference 0x7f09001b
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void hackit.selina.com.nativeoc.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x740452a0 self=0xb4db6500
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=13617 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f8bb34
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 302916881 9052184 98 ) utm=17 stm=13 core=0 HZ=100
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0xbe176000-0xbe178000 stackSize=8MB
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 00370e01  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+160)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0035046f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+150)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0025a725  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+740)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0025ae7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+74)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 00351231  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+708)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 0032cd0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+412)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 00278619  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+344)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 00110cfd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+928)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 00111f95  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+36)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 00000bcb  /data/app/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc-2/lib/arm/libnativeit.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+82)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 00000989  /data/app/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc-2/lib/arm/libnativeit.so (Java_hackit_selina_com_nativeoc_MainActivity_onCreate+156)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 000eaa29  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 00774d41  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (???)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at hackit.selina.com.nativeoc.MainActivity.onCreate(Native method)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-05 11:14:53.361 13617-13617/hackit.selina.com.nativeoc A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]
12-05 11:14:53.515 13617-13617/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting...
12-05 11:14:53.516 13617-13617/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Aborting thread:
12-05 11:14:53.516 13617-13617/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
12-05 11:14:53.516 13617-13617/?
```

In [JNI Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html), I found that there is a **NewGlobalRef** may solve this, I tried but it didn't work, can anybody help me?

Comment: Without line numbers, it's hard to interpret the error message. I would strongly recommend to use the [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts.html#naa) framework, it can help you reduce boilerplate code significantly.

Comment: You're not doing *any* error checking.  Any one of your calls might have failed.  You need to check every call for an error.  Adding debugging output will also likely help.

Comment: In the error message, 0x7f04001b is the value of R.layout.activity_main, the value is right, but it seems that it can't find the layout xml, i check the [JNI tip](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html), it mentions **NewGlobalRef**，I tried but it failed.@ Alex Cohn I know the NativeActivity is better, but I need to use MainActivity to implement, I think it just needs to bind the id with the xml file, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: You can **`extend`** the NativeActivity class in Java, if that is required. On the other hand, it is not a recommended practice to define either public methods or system callbacks as **`native`**. *onCreate()** is both. If you use a Java wrapper that calls **super.onCreate()** and then continues to a `private native nativeOnCreate()`, your C++ code will be much cleaner, and you have a better chance to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Here may be the root problem: `GetIntField()` should be called not on a **jclass**, but on an object of this class. You need a live object of class `com/nisl/hack/nativeoc/R$layout` to extract the `jnit activityMain` from it.

Comment: @Alex Cohn R.layout.actiivty_main is public static, so I used GetStaticIntField(class,fieldID). In addition, the jint activityMain is correct, but it seems that the id can't find its corresponding layout file

Comment: but `setContentView()` expects a **View**, not and **int**

Comment: Yeah， I used the wrong parament type  jmethodID setContentView = (*env).GetMethodID(thisClassGlobal,"setContentView","(Landroid/view/View;)V");, after I change it to (I)V, it worked! Thank you!